# Trying to get highcharts waterfall chart working using justpy, getting "Unexpected text after end of JSON value"

Tags: python, highcharts

I'm trying to get highcharts waterfall chart working using justpy, getting "Unexpected text after end of JSON value". Can anyone spot the error in the below that would be causing an html error? Some character is somewhere that it shouldn't be? I don't have a good eye for HTML. I am using a justpy app in python to run the chart, thanks

```
import justpy as jp

chart_def="""
{
    chart: {
        type: 'waterfall'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Waterfall'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'USD'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>${point.y:,.2f}</b> USD'
    },

    series: [{
            name: 'Start',
            y: 120000
        }, {
            name: 'Product Revenue',
            y: 569000
        }, {
            name: 'Service Revenue',
            y: 231000
        }, {
            name: 'Positive Balance',
            isIntermediateSum: true
        }, {
            name: 'Fixed Costs',
            y: -342000
        }, {
            name: 'Variable Costs',
            y: -233000
        }, {
            name: 'Balance',
            isSum: true
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
            },
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        pointPadding: 0
    }]
}
"""

def app():
    wp = jp.QuasarPage()
    h1 = jp.QDiv(a=wp, text="Title here",classes="text-h2 text-center q-pa-md")
    hc = jp.HighCharts(a=wp,options=chart_def)    
    return wp

jp.justpy(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a mistake in your series configuration. Try the following code:

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'waterfall'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Waterfall'
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'USD'
    }
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>${point.y:,.2f}</b> USD'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      name: 'Start',
      y: 120000
    }, {
      name: 'Product Revenue',
      y: 569000
    }, {
      name: 'Service Revenue',
      y: 231000
    }, {
      name: 'Positive Balance',
      isIntermediateSum: true
    }, {
      name: 'Fixed Costs',
      y: -342000
    }, {
      name: 'Variable Costs',
      y: -233000
    }, {
      name: 'Balance',
      isSum: true
    }],

    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    pointPadding: 0
  }]
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/80zfLta2/